# Rigid Body and Soft Body animation

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, soft-body

I would like to create an animation like this:

[image: r]

https://www.instagram.com/p/C1xkNMuvFmh/

I'm not being able to create this jiggly effect and also to interact rigid bodies with soft bodies/cloth.

Can someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create that animation by using rigid body spheres, with collision physics, falling onto a soft body rendering mesh (which will react to the collision physics) and a non-rendering, animated or passive, rigid body mesh (which will stop the balls from falling further.)

If you do so, keep in mind that the rigid bodies will technically "rule" the simulation: the rigid body physics will act first, and the soft body will adjust to the positions of the rigid bodies.

It is technically possible to create this as a fully interactive simulation, by using a soft body simulation on a single object that contains all of the balls and the surface onto which they fall, with self-collision enabled, with differences in rigidity provided by vertex groups and topological differences, but in practice, it's difficult to simulate that level of rigidity on soft bodies, and is expensive in terms of performance, and it's easier to just let the rigid bodies rule the sim.

Comment: So it's not possible to interact rigid body and soft body 'natively'?

Comment: No-- it's not even possible to interact two different soft body sims natively.  Whenever multiple sims run, one has to be in charge.